# How to encrypt a sqlite db file with server side java so a flex/air client can read it?

Tags: java, apache-flex, sqlite, encryption

We are trying to create a sqlite db file using java on the server, and encrypt it.  Then we send the encrypted db file to a client's pc, which has an Adobe Air desktop app running.  The air app then needs to be able to open/read-from the encrypted db file (client is read-only).

We are using java 1.6, flex/actionscript 4.5, and Air 3.1.

We can create the sqlite db file on the server and send it to the client, and it can be read by the client without issues, when we do not encrypt it.  But we are having trouble with the encryption part.

We've read quite a lot of documentation about Actionscript's ability to open encrypted sqlite files using AES + CCM ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS8AFC5E35-DC79-4082-9AD4-DE1A2B41DAAF.html#WS61068DCE-9499-4d40-82B8-B71CC35D832C ).  And we're trying to use java's crypto package to encrypt the sqlite db file.

The encryption is important because we don't want the client to be able to open the sqlite db file with any sqlite browser, only with our Air application.

Has anyone done this before and can point us in the right direction?

Comment: Is the nature of the application very secure? Advanced users will be able to reverse the methods used to encrypt the file and encryption alone would not be enough to stop a determined user.

Comment: Remember that for your Air application to decrypt the file, it must have the decryption key.  And if the decryption key is in a program on the user's computer, a skilled user will extract it and publish it.

Comment: We're not so concerned, yet, about a very determined user.  Just a lay user at this point.   We were thinking that there would be two parts to the key, one that is compiled into the air executable, and the other that is sent along with the db file.

Comment: At this point, however, we're just trying to figure out how to get the encryption on the java side and decryption on the air side working.  What would the java code look like?  What would the actionscript code look like?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why not just send the encrypted file over an secure amf channel? Should you require any additional level of security, how about just doing a simple xor encryption? Cryptography gets quite complex and having two different technologies whereby one encrypts and the other decrypts - ish - things could get hairy.
Xor encryption involves having a secret key. The first character of data is xor'ed with the first character of the key, the second with the second, and so on, until you reach the end of the key, whereafter the next character of data is then xor'ed with the first character of the data, and so on, until you reach the end of the data stream. To decrypt is exactly the same algorithm.
Of course you can pick a million ways on how to generate keys.
Personally, I wouldn't trust the current actionscript crypto libraries to do this for me. But this is purely a matter of opinion. And to rewrite one ...
Good luck in any case.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  We are at the point of looking into something just as you suggested.  It isn't a matter of sending the file over a secured amf channel.  The issue is that once the file lands on the client's pc, it stays there so they can reopen it anytime they want.  So we don't want a user to be able to open the sqlite db file with just any sqlite browser; they should only be able to open it with our app.

Comment: The only other suggestion I have is that you encrypt the data that you store in the sqlite db. So upon inserting / updating you do encrypt and upon selecting you do decrypt. If you want you can go as far as to use the encrypt and decrypt functions on table creation so that even your tables and columns are obfuscated. I guess the easiest way to achieve this is to extend the sqlite jdbc adaptor. Then your encrypted jdbc adaptor can be used in your db analyzer tool (squirrel or aqua or whatever) and in java, and in action script simply encrypt whenever you insert and decrypt when you delete